# Django FutureFqType matching query does not exist

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-workbench

I'm setting up a new website using Django, and want to get an object name from
sql . But it keep output the error objects.get matching query does not exist
Where do I need to modify the code?

views

```
def predict1(request):
   name = ''
   loginstatus = False
   try:
        name = request.session['name']
        loginstatus = True
   except:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/?back=未來型預測')


   category_id = FutureMember.objects.get(member_name=name).type
   cname = FutureFqType.objects.get(type_id=category_id).type_name
   return render_to_response('predicts.html', {'cname': cname,'loginstatus': loginstatus, 'name': name})
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<div><h2>根據投資人屬性測驗結果，您屬於<font color="#75CA20">{{ cname }} 您好!&nbsp;{{ name }}</font></h2>
    <form action="/predict/" method="post">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

models

```
class FutureFqType(models.Model):
    type_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=2)
    type_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    type_describe = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    type_score = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'future_fq_type'
```

I expect the output of {{ cname }} to be data, but the actual can't output 
It comes out an error FutureFqType matching query does not exist.

new views

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


def predict1(request):
    loginstatus = False
    try:
        name = request.session["name"]
        loginstatus = True
    except KeyError:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/login/?back=未來型預測")
    category_id = get_object_or_404(FutureMember, member_name=name).type
    cname = get_object_or_404(FutureFqType, type_id=category_id).type_name
    return render_to_response(
        "predicts.html",
        {"cname": cname, "loginstatus": loginstatus, "name": name},
    )
```

page output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a501.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
 from django.shortcuts import HttpResponse, get_object_or_404, redirect, render


def predict1(request):
    loginstatus = False
    try:
        name = request.session["name"]
        loginstatus = True
    except KeyError:
        return redirect("/login/?back=未來型預測")
    try:
        member = FutureMember.objects.get(member_name=name)
    except FutureMember.DoesNotExist:
        msg = f"<h1>FutureMember not found with member_name=`{name}`</h1>"
        return HttpResponse(msg)
    try:
        fqtype = FutureFqType.objects.get(type_id=member.type)
    except FutureFqType.DoesNotExist:
        msg = f"<h1>FutureFqType not found with type_id=`{member.type}`</h1>"
        return HttpResponse(msg)
    else:
        cname = fqtype.type_name
    data = {"cname": cname, "loginstatus": loginstatus, "name": name}
    return render("predicts.html", data)
```

Comment: I add the code you suggest but the page still can't open, still need your help!

Comment: But it came out . You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.